# How to Represent a Single Statistic in SQL Database?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table (SQLite database), Listing, that has a datetime field.  For my program, I need to know the most recent time field my program has seen.  However, I don't store all listings the program has seen into the database.

So my question is, what is the usual way to store data like "most recently seen object", which is a single record, into a database?  Is there something more elegant than making another table that has one record with a datetime field?

Comment: `select max(datetimecol) from sometable`

Comment: Not all listings the program has seen may be stored in the table.

Comment: Are you trying to display that to a user? like a user logs in and then sees a post for example and then next time they log in they will see a last seen on that post?

Comment: No, it's for a scraper that runs periodically; stop if I've already seen these listings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to save all records into your database, then you get the `max()` suggested by @GordonLinoff. What's your problem in save the data? If you hope keep database size small, You can add a trigger which delete oldest rows during new `INSERT`s.

But I don't understand properly your example. Can you give us some part of code?

Comment: Ok, I can add an extra field that will indicate a "priority" status.  The problem would be that the number of listings seen is much greater than the number of listings saved.